# Parameters from view not getting to controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagedlist

I'm implementing Troy Goode's PagedList in one of my views (ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor).  The challenge I'm having is when I click on a page number link, the request is routed to my HttpGet method, which just returns the empty page (ready for input).

My View Model:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public SelectList IndustrySelectList { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<KeyValuePair<string, SearchResult>> SearchResults { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Search(string searchTerm = "")
    {
        SearchViewModel vm = new SearchViewModel
        {
            IndustrySelectList = new SelectList(_Industries.AsEnumerable(), "IndustryId", "IndustryName"),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = 1,
                ItemsPerPage = 25,
                TotalItems = 0
            }
        };

        return View(vm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(string[] industries, string searchTerm = "", int page = 1)
    {
        SearchViewModel vm = null;

        _url = "http://localhost/MasterNode/masternode.cgi?zoom_query={" + searchTerm + "}&zoom_xml=1&zoom_page={startPage?}&zoom_per_page=1000";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int pageSize = 5;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            vm = new SearchViewModel
            {
                IndustrySelectList = new SelectList(_Industries.AsEnumerable(), "IndustryId", "IndustryName")
            };
        }
        else
        {
            _request = new SearchRequest(SearchRequest.EnvironmentTypes.Development, "", _url, searchTerm, SearchRequest.SearchType.AllWords, 1000);
            sb.Append(GetResults(_url));
            _results = new Dictionary<string, SearchResult>();
            ParseResults(sb);
            GetDetailInformationForResults(searchTerm);

            vm = new SearchViewModel
            {
                IndustrySelectList = new SelectList(_Industries.AsEnumerable(), "IndustryId", "IndustryName"),
                SearchResults = _results.ToList<KeyValuePair<string, SearchResult>>().ToPagedList(1, 25),
                PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
                {
                    CurrentPage = page,
                    ItemsPerPage = pageSize,
                    TotalItems = _results.Count()
                }
            };
        }
        return View(vm);
    }
```

View:

```
@model MultiView.OmniGuide.ViewModels.SearchViewModel
@using MultiView.OmniGuide.HtmlHelpers
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home")) 
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.IndustrySelectList)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.PagingInfo)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.SearchResults)
    <table width="70%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="background: #fff">
                <input id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" type="text" class="SearchBox" style="width: 450px" />
                <input type="submit" class="SearchButton" value=" " />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="left">
            <td align="left" style="background: #fff">
                @Html.ActionLink("MultiView corporate site", "Search")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" align="center" style="width: 450px">
                @{
                    Html.Telerik().PanelBar()
                        .Name("searchPanel")
                        .Items(title =>
                        {
                            title.Add()
                                .Text("Filter by Industry")
                                .Content(() =>
                                {
                                    @Html.RenderPartial("_Industry", @Model);
                                });
                        })
                        .Render();       
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    if (Model.SearchResults != null)
    {
        <table width="70%">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Company Image
                </th>
                <th class="tableHeader">
                    Company Name Here
                </th>
                <th class="tableHeader">
                    Website
                </th>
            </tr>     
        @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MultiView.OmniGuide.Models.SearchResult> itm in Model.SearchResults)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td align="left" style="width: 15%">
                    @itm.Value.DetailedInfo.LogoURL 
                </td>
                <td align="left" style="width: 60%">
                    <p style="text-align: left">
                     @itm.Value.DetailedInfo.DescriptionAbbreviated
                     <br />
                     </p>
                    @Html.AnchorLink(itm.Value.FoundURL, itm.Value.FoundURL)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    @itm.Value.FoundURL
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </table>    
        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.SearchResults, page => Url.Action("Search", "Home", new { page }))
    }
}
```

When text is supplied in the input box and the button is clicked, the requested is routed to the HttpPost method.  In looking at the request.form values, all expected data but paging information is present.

```
?HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys  
{string[5]}
    [0]: "IndustrySelectList"
    [1]: "PagingInfo"
    [2]: "SearchResults"
    [3]: "searchTerm"
    [4]: "industries"
```

Any help with this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By clicking the button you are submitting the form which is why it is doing the `httppost`.  The next page link is hitting the httpget correctly but you are not passing it any information to so that it knows what to `get`.  The get needs other information, like what page you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

The page number links fire a `GET` request, so you'll need to make sure that your `GET` action  can handle the full search as well, so will need to get the page number and industries array - using defaults for when those parameters aren't available.

e.g.

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Search(string searchTerm = "", int page = 1, 
     string industries = "")
{
    //.....
}
```

You'll need to modify the pager link like this to pass industries to the get action.

`@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.SearchResults, page => Url.Action("Search", "Home", new { page, industries = string.Join(",", Model.IndustrySelectList.Where( x => x.Selected).Select( x => x.Text)) }))`

It's not clear to me from your code where the post action is getting `string[] industries` from, or what it is doing with it, but you will need some way of passing this same this to your get action, probably as a single string that is comma separated.  The example I've provided assumed you are taken it from the select list on the viewmodel

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I've changed the GET action to handle the full search also.  But now when I click on a page link, say for page 2, that GET action gets called 2 times.  Or 4 times if I click the link for page 4.

Comment: that sounds a bit odd - clicking on a link should only request the action once.  Perhaps your get action is calling itself.  Step through the code and see if that is the case.